# Absolute import in python3 but it cant find my package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

so I have this directory structure:

```
/pkg
    /__init__.py
    /script1.py
    /dir1
         /__init__.py
         /file.json
         /dir2
              /__init__.py
              /script2.py
```

As you can see, I have two script files, script1.py and script2.py, what I'm trying to do is to import script1.py from script2.py, so I did

```
import pkg.script1
```

but it is telling me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'
```

ports and did

```
from ... import script1
```

but I get this error

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: This is an attempted relative import, not an absolute import.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your commandline (the important missing information) this is only a guess.  You can see a [writeup I did on this here](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness).

You're *probably* running `python pkg/dir1/dir2/script2.py` which is going to put `pkg/dir1/dir2` on the python path (and not `.` as you want) -- this leads to the error messages you see because you are in fact *not* a package at that depth (and don't have `pkg` importable on any of the `sys.path` roots).  You'd also see the same problem in python 2.

You should almost always use the `-m` approach when calling scripts that are modules.  In your case it would be `python -m pkg.dir1.dir2.script2`